# View folders in remote server in a GUI

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I am connected to a remote server through the Ubuntu terminal. 
I am wondering if there is any way to actually browse files and folders of the remote server independently from the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

In the main menu choose "Places -> Connect to Server ... ". Then choose connection method "SSH" and type your credentials. That's it.

Btw, the question is better suited for http://www.superuser.com.